# How to find dept name that has the highest average salary within two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having two tables

```
Employee
Id
Name
Salary
DepartmentId
```

and

```
Departament
Id
Name
```

How can I get the highest average salary within two tables
like

```
Joe and Max belong to dept 1 so, avg is (70K+90K)/2
= 80K
```

and

```
Henry and Sam belog to dept 2, avg is (80K + 60K)/2=70k
```

so How to select the greatest avg salary by depto?, in this case

```
IT 80K
```

i have been trying:

'group the salary by each department and use the Max function to obtain the highest one.

```
select 
    Department.Name as Department,
    T.M as Salary
from
    Employee,
    Department,
    (select DepartmentId as ID, Max(Salary) as M from Employee group by DepartmentId) as T
where
    Employee.Salary = T.M and
    Department.Id = T.ID and 
    Employee.DepartmentId = Department.Id
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr5lC.png)

Comment: Instead of Max you can try using Avg as well ? which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

If multiple department having same maximum avg salary then this solution will return multiple rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT d.Id, d.Name, AVG(e.Salary) avg_salary, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY AVG(e.Salary) DESC) AS rank_
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Departament d ON e.DepartmentId = d.Id
GROUP BY d.Id, d.Name
)T
WHERE rank_ = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the average just for the department, you can use in this way.

```
select DepartmentId as ID,  de.name as Deptname,  Avg(Salary) as M from Employee em1 
       join Department de on de.departmentID = em1.DepartmentId 
          group by DepartmentId, de.name
```

If you want employee name along with highest average  then you can use this approach as well.

```
select 
Deptname as Department,
e.Name as Employeename, 
z.M as Salary
from
Employee e 
join 
( select DepartmentId,Deptname, M, row_number() (order by m desc) rownum from (   select DepartmentId as ID,  de.name as Deptname,  Avg(Salary) as M from Employee em1 
       join Department de on de.departmentID = em1.DepartmentId 
          group by DepartmentId, de.name) as T) z
on 
e.DepartmentId = T.DepartmentId  and z.rownum = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a full answer, you should provide DDL, sample data and desired result.
If I understand you correctly, you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT DepartmentID, AVG(Salary) AS AverageSalaryForDept
FROM Employee
GROUP BY DepartmentID
ORDER BY AverageSalaryForDept DESC;
```

This will give you all the averages, ordered from the highest to the lowest. Now if you want just the top one, add a FETCH clause:

```
SELECT DepartmentID, AVG(Salary) AS AverageSalaryForDept
FROM Employee
GROUP BY DepartmentID
ORDER BY AverageSalaryForDept DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

HTH

Comment: I think you're missing the part to fetch department name considering only the first table? The question has asked to display the department name too for which we need to link the second table too.